# How to Detect and Immediately Refresh a Blank Page in Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python Selenium script that opens a website for testing purposes. However, I encounter an issue where the website occasionally goes blank and stops loading when using Selenium ChromeDriver (approximately 30-40% of the time). When I open the website in a regular Chrome browser, it loads without any problems every time.

Here are my ChromeDriver options:

```py
def setup_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("--disk-cache=yes")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
    options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=ChromeService(
            executable_path=Config.get_chrome_driver_path(),
            desired_capabilities=caps),
        options=options)
    return driver
```

And this is how I open the page:

```py
driver.get(SIGN_IN_URL)
```

My question is: How can I detect when the page has stopped loading and is blank (the browser's network has stopped fetching data) and immediately refresh the page? I want to achieve an immediate refresh upon page load stop without using timeouts or waiting for elements to load.